# Communication between a Mac app & local website/server

Tags: objective-c, macos, webserver, localhost

I want to control a mac app via a local website. I think the best way is to create a webserver with my mac app and then to send (primarily) integer values from the website and vice versa.
I found already CocoaHTTPServer, but I'm not sure how to do it.

For start with I want to have a slider on the website, that updates a slider in my mac application (and vice versa)

Comment: Have you compiled and run the samples from that project?

Comment: when you say "local" website, do you mean one that *runs* on the Macintosh with the app you're trying to control?  Or just a website within the same subnet?

Comment: I mean a website that runs on the Mac with the app. And yes I tried the examples, but I still have no idea how communicate properly.

Answer (score 0):

You will initiate on a separate thread or operation the web server and always wait for incoming requests. Whenever you receive a request you will handle it accordingly.

Also, if you are using this: [https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer/](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer)
then there are a few examples that show how to do it. Copy the code from there to begin with the web server handling requests. After that, think through what you want to send and what you want to do. Build a form or something for the web site and submit a request to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

CocoaHTTPServer will let you **embed** the web server into your application, which is a fine solution for what you're trying to accomplish.

Some thoughts on how to engineer it:

- You'll need to subclass HTTPConnection.
- Model your solution on the PostHTTPServer example.
- You could get the data you want to send into the URL. Something like `POST http://localhost:12345/updateSlider/123`. (You probably don't need an actual POST, but no reason it wouldn't work. Technically a PUT would be more correct.)
- Start by handling that part – where the browser sends a value to your application. To generate POST/PUT requests for testing purposes, use `curl`, or else build a static page and open it in your browser.
- When you get that working, then worry about presenting a web page to the user.